# How to compute the frequency bands corresponding to the scale level in Discrete wavelet transform

Tags: discrete-wavelet-transform

I am using MATLAB's built-in function to compute maximal overlap discrete wavelet transform (`modwt`)and want to know the frequency bands at each scale level. I am looking for a mathematical equation that I can use to compute the bands in each level. Given the sampling frequency $f_s$, the length $N$, and the levels.

Answer (score 0):

The length $N$ does not influence the frequency decomposition.
Each level will split the lower frequency content into $2$ bands:
$$f_n = \frac{f_s}{2^{n+1}}$$ where $f_n$ is the split frequency, $n$ the level and $f_s$ the sampling rate.

For example, here is level $n = 3$ decomposition with $f_s = 500\, \texttt{Hz}$:

[image]

Comment: I found this article by Parameswariah, Chethan, and Mickey Cox. "Frequency characteristics of wavelets." IEEE Transactions on Power Delivery 17.3 (2002): 800-804. Their explanation varies from yours.

Answer (score -1):

I found a paper that provides the equation:

[Parameswariah, Chethan, and Mickey Cox. "Frequency characteristics of wavelets." IEEE Transactions on Power Delivery 17.3 (2002): 800-804.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1022806)

Comment: Maybe edit this with the relevant formula you found in that paper?

Comment: and especially since many of us are not IEEE nor have access to a university library that gets the IEEE transactions.  so we can't even scan the document without paying IEEE paywall.